How should I initialize pthread mutexes in shared memory, since at program start they can be already initialized?
I'm using shared, robust pthread mutexes to protect some shared memory areas I have in my application. Since my program is managed by a systemd service, it could potentially be restarted, in which case the shared memory segment would have already been existing, and it would contain a valid initialized mutex. Robust mutexes detect if the locking thread has crashed, but I couldn't find anything regarding double initialization if the crashed thread wasn't holding it: how should I initialize a mutex that can potentially had already been initialized?
For what I understood, calling pthread_mutex_init() on an already initialized mutex is UB, pthread_mutex_lock() returns error EOWNERDEAD only if the mutex was being held at crash, but it also returns EINVAL if the mutex hasn't been initialized. So, should I be fine in trying to lock the mutex at startup, and checking whether it returns EINVAL (only if it does, I initialize it)?

EDIT would simply reset all the memory with memset(ptr, 0, size) effectively destroy the mutex, allowing me then to reinitialize it? Or does it leave some traces in the kernel, leaking resources?

EDIT 2
The complete scenario is this: I have one father process and two children, all managed by systemd. The father is responsible to open the shared memory areas (one for each children) and place a mutex in each one. Since this will run on a edge device, during normal functioning it will cleanly exit and shutdown the machine, so no problems there. But I need to keep this running, both for availability reasons and because the father process is the one detecting when it should shutdown the machine (by reading an external signal), so in the systemd service I set up to always restart it. For the children, this is not a problem, since they are not the ones with the code to initialize the mutex, they simply open the shared area. they get restarted too if the father is restarted (not mandatory but useful). This way, however, if there is a restart of the father service, the memory area is still there, with the mutex, and the father will execute the code trying to initialize the mutex.

Calling pthread_mutex_lock on an uninitialized mutex produces UB for all mutex types.  It is not safe to rely on getting an EINVAL in that case.

When your application is restarted, can there be other processes already using the mutex and shared memory?  Clients, or something?  Because this sounds like something that will require a deeper mitigation than anything you seem presently to be thinking about.  In that vein, then, can you explain more fully how this shared memory and the mutex within it are used?

thanks @JohnBollinger , I added an edit in the question


how should I initialize a mutex that can potentially had already been initialized?

There is no safe way to do this.  You need to know whether to initialize or not.
Since the "father" alone is responsible for setting up the shared memory and mutex, a reasonable approach would be for it to do this from scratch every time it starts.  There are at least two good ways to do this:

if the father is responsible for starting the children itself, then it can use anonymous shared memory, which persists only as long as at least one process holds it open, and which will not be visible to separate, independent runs of the father.  Its children will inherit it across a fork, however, and by default, across an exec, too.  With this approach, the father doesn't need to be concerned with whether the mutex is already initialized, because it will always need to create a new one.

The father can detect whether the shared memory already exists when it starts, and if so, either

assume that the mutex is already initialized, OR
unlink the shared memory and create new, and a new mutex.

This approach has potential timing issues, in that the children must not attempt to access the mutex before the father has initialized it.  But if that's a problem on restart, then it's also a problem on the first start, so you would already have it.



Thanks! Two questions tho: how can I make anonymous shared memory, that survives an exec? IIUC, an exec completely substitute the binary running, as well as the file descriptors and all the memory mapped (especially if that's obtained by a simple fork in the code, as I assume you are referring to with anonymous memory?). Second: so unlinking the memory will make the kernel "deregister" the mutex? That was the part I was interested to. And I suppose that memsetting the memory to 0 wouldn't work, because the kernel wouldn't care of the content of the memory, just that it exists?

@AlessandroBertulli, "anonymous" was a poor choice of words on my part.  Details depend on what shared-memory mechanism you are using, but with POSIX shared memory objects, for example, you can turn off the close-on-exec flag of the shared memory object via fcntl(), in which case it is preserved across execs.  You still need somehow to tell the exec'ed program what the file descriptor number is, and it must map it for itself, but this way it can avoid opening it.  Which allows that the parent unlinks that object immediately after opening it, after which it cannot be accessed by name.

thank you! I need to investigate how to do that but it's definetly a possibility. And what about the second thing? Is unlinking the memory enough for Linux to stop tracking the mutex? Would memsetting it to 0 have achieved the same?

@AlessandroBertulli, the system has to be robust against issues arising from programs failing to cleanly destroy mutexes, whether through programming negligence or because of program crashes.  It is reasonable to assume that once the shared memory object containing it is removed (not just unlinked) there are no lingering traces of the mutex.
